# hadoop get max value in reducer

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm new in hadoop. I have the data: NAICS, Area and Wage from: https://data.ny.gov/Economic-Development/Quarterly-Census-of-Employment-and-Wages-Annual-Da/shc7-xcbw.

My goal is to find in every NAICS the area, where the sum of Wage is the biggest in the statistic using java hadoop. So far I made the Mapper, which will create the context of such form: <NAICS_Area, Wage>, so key is the NAICS and Area connected with "_" and Reducer:

```
public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text,LongWritable,Text,LongWritable> {
private LongWritable result = new LongWritable();
//private HashMap<String, Long> naicsMax = new HashMap<String, Long>();

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  long sum = 0;
  for (LongWritable val : values) {
    sum += val.get();
  }
  result.set(sum);
  context.write(key, result);
}
}
```

which will so far create the result such as <NAICS_Area, sum of Wage for given area> , so I have for every Area in every NAICS total sum of Wage, but now I don't know how to continue in my goal. I need to get maximal sum of Wages for Area in each NAICS and I don't know how. Did I make any mistake in my planning mapper or the context like <NAICS_Area, Wage> is correct?

Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: What version of hadoop?  Suggest you post your mapper too.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the output of this reducer given to another map reduce job . 
The mapper of that job can have the following logic,

1. Split the NAICS and Area in the key  and give just the NAICS in the
   output key portion.
2. Append the Area with sum of wages with comma as delimiter and give
   that in the output value portion.

Reducer may have the logic to find the maximum of the sum of wages for each NAICS_Area.

1. Iterate over the key (NAICS) and split the value for each iteration.
2. Get the sum value and cast it to long and then implement the maximum
   logic.

,

```
public void reduce(Text NAICS, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)       throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
     long max =0;
    for (Text value : values) 
        {
           String[] areaWages = value.toString().Split(',');
           String sumString = areaWages[0];
           long sum = Long.parseLong(sumString);
           String AREA = areaWages[1];
    if(sum > max)
        {
            max = sum;
        }
    }
     context.write(NAICS, new TextAREA))
    }
```